# Pandas how to perform conditional selection on MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the [sample data file](http://pbpython.com/extras/sales-funnel.xlsx), and I performed the following operation in ipython notebook:

```
!curl -O http://pbpython.com/extras/sales-funnel.xlsx

df = pd.read_excel('./sales-funnel.xlsx')
df['Status'] = df['Status'].astype('category')
df["Status"].cat.set_categories(["won","pending","presented","declined"],inplace=True)

table = pd.pivot_table(df,
               index=['Manager', 'Status'],
               values=['Price', 'Quantity'],
               columns=['Product'],
               aggfunc={'Price':[np.sum, np.mean], 'Quantity':len},
               fill_value=0
              )
```

This is what the data looks like in `table`:

[image]

I want to select `(Manager=="Debra Henley") & (Status=="won")` and it works with the `query` method:

```
table.query('(Manager=="Debra Henley") & (Status=="won")')
```

But how do you perform the same selection with `loc`? I tried this but does not work:

```
table.loc[['Debra Henley', 'won']]
```

What do you guys usually use when dealing with MultiIndex? What's the best way to do it？

---

Update: found two solutions so far:

```
table.xs(('Debra Henley','won'), level=('Manager', 'Status'))
table.loc[[('Debra Henley', 'won')]]
```

So I guess `tuples` should be used instead of `lists` when indexing with MultiIndex?

Comment: `.loc` is the quicker method in this case, because your data is already in the correct form.

You are absolutely correct that multi-level indexing must be done with tuples (or at least certainly not with lists); this is because a list (or numpy array) is used to select data on the same 'level' (if you think of indexing with a tuple (multi-index) as going deeper, then a list goes 'wider'); for example, see what you get with the following: `table.loc[['Debra Henley', 'Fred Anderson']]` and
`table.loc[[('Debra Henley','won'), ('Fred Anderson','pending')]]`

Comment: @KenWei  " your data is already in the correct form", what do you mean by the correct form?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear, and would probably best explain with an example: Suppose you wanted to get the `pending` row of each manager. You can do this with `table.xs('pending', level = 'Status')`, whereas with `.loc` you would need to swap the `Status` and `Manager` levels, then do `table.loc['pending']` (so I would have described this case as having the data in the 'wrong' form). (Basically, if you don't need to supply the `level` argument, you can probably get the same result with `.loc`.)

Comment: Also, there are some subtleties about retaining the index levels in the output, depending on whether you do `.loc` with a tuple, a tuple within a list, or a string, and the `drop_level` argument in `.xs()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
table.loc[[('Debra Henley', 'won')]]
```

to return a pandas data frame or you can use:

```
table.loc[('Debra Henley','won')]
```

to return a pandas series.

You can refer to the [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index) documentation.

Comment: To add some more color to this answer, `pandas` uses tuples to reference elements of a `pd.MultiIndex`

Answer (score 5):

Your canonical answer is provided by @ScottBoston.

I'll add this for breadth and perspective in addition to @jezrael's `IndexSlice` approach.
You can also use [***`pd.DataFrame.xs`***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) to take a cross-section

```
table.xs(['Debra Henley', 'won'])

                Product    
Quantity  len   CPU                1
                Maintenance        0
                Monitor            0
                Software           0
Price     mean  CPU            65000
                Maintenance        0
                Monitor            0
                Software           0
          sum   CPU            65000
                Maintenance        0
                Monitor            0
                Software           0
Name: (Debra Henley, won), dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

For simplier selections (only index or only columns) use [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) approach or selecting by `tuples`.

Another more general solution with [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
#output is df
print (table.loc[[idx['Debra Henley','won']]])
                    Quantity                               Price              \
                         len                                mean               
Product                  CPU Maintenance Monitor Software    CPU Maintenance   
Manager      Status                                                            
Debra Henley won           1           0       0        0  65000           0   


                                        sum                               
Product             Monitor Software    CPU Maintenance Monitor Software  
Manager      Status                                                       
Debra Henley won          0        0  65000           0       0        0
```

---

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
#output is series
print (table.loc[idx['Debra Henley','won'],:])
Quantity  len   CPU                1
                Maintenance        0
                Monitor            0
                Software           0
Price     mean  CPU            65000
                Maintenance        0
                Monitor            0
                Software           0
          sum   CPU            65000
                Maintenance        0
                Monitor            0
                Software           0
Name: (Debra Henley, won), dtype: int64
```

But it is better for more complicated selections - if need filter index and columns together - one `xs` doesnt work:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
#select all rows where first level is Debra Henley in index and 
#in columns second level is len and sum
print (table.loc[idx['Debra Henley',:], idx[:, ['len', 'sum'], :]])
                       Quantity                               Price  \
                            len                                 sum   
Product                     CPU Maintenance Monitor Software    CPU   
Manager      Status                                                   
Debra Henley won              1           0       0        0  65000   
             pending          1           2       0        0  40000   
             presented        1           0       0        2  30000   
             declined         2           0       0        0  70000   



Product                Maintenance Monitor Software  
Manager      Status                                  
Debra Henley won                 0       0        0  
             pending         10000       0        0  
             presented           0       0    20000  
             declined            0       0        0
```